# ES6 assign values from one object to another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

trying to assign values from one object to another after using the `filter()` function to find the object i want to assign the data to.
my first attempt which didn't work looked like this:

```
if (this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id).length) {
    this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0] = {
        id: this.editForm.id,
        bid: this.editForm.bid,
        budget: this.editForm.budget,
        country: this.editForm.country,
        desc: this.editForm.desc,
        device: this.editForm.device,
        profile_id: this.editForm.profile_id,
        user_id: this.userId,
        widget_list_id: this.editForm.widget_list_id,
        widget_type: this.editForm.widget_type
    }
}
```

so i tried finding elegant solution but the only way i can get the logic to work is this:

```
if (this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id).length) {
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].id = this.editForm.id;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].bid = this.editForm.bid;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].budget = this.editForm.budget;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].country = this.editForm.country;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].desc = this.editForm.desc;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].device = this.editForm.device;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].profile_id = this.editForm.profile_id;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].user_id = this.userId;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].widget_list_id = this.editForm.widget_list_id;
        this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0].widget_type = this.editForm.widget_type;
}
```

which i clearly everything but elegant. any idea why my first attemplt didn't work?

Comment: Why not go with a single line of code using the spread operator `...`? `this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0] = { ...this.editForm }`. If you want it less experimental, use `Object.assign()` instead: `this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0] = Object.assign({}, this.editForm)`

Comment: [Don't repeat yourself!!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)!!! Use a temporary variable for the filtered array (which also does execute all the filtering only once):

```
const lasts = this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id);
if (lasts.length) {
    lasts[0].id = this.editForm.id;
    lasts[0].bid = this.editForm.bid;
    lasts[0].budget = this.editForm.budget;
    lasts[0].country = this.editForm.country;
    lasts[0].desc = this.editForm.desc;
    lasts[0].device = this.editForm.device;
    lasts[0].profile_id = this.editForm.profile_id;
    lasts[0].user_id = this.userId;
    lasts[0].widget_type = this.editForm.widget_type;
    lasts[0].widget_list_id = this.editForm.widget_list_id;
}
```

Further, more temporary variables:

```
const lasts = this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id);
if (lasts.length) {
    const last = lasts[0];
    const editForm = this.editForm;
    last.id = editForm.id;
    last.bid = editForm.bid;
    last.budget = editForm.budget;
    last.country = editForm.country;
    last.desc = editForm.desc;
    last.device = editForm.device;
    last.profile_id = editForm.profile_id;
    last.user_id = this.userId;
    last.widget_type = editForm.widget_type;
    last.widget_list_id = editForm.widget_list_id;
}
```

After that, you need to know a bit more about the built-in methods. There's the [Array `find` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) that filters out a single item (the first which matches a predicate) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), that copies all enumerable properties from one object to an other (which only works if your `editForm` has only the properties that you want to copy).

```
const last = this.sets.find(s => s.id === res.body.last_id);
if (last) {
    Object.assign(last, this.editForm);
    last.user_id = this.userId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
if (this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id).length) {
    Object.assign(this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0], {
        id: this.editForm.id,
        bid: this.editForm.bid,
        budget: this.editForm.budget,
        country: this.editForm.country,
        desc: this.editForm.desc,
        device: this.editForm.device,
        profile_id: this.editForm.profile_id,
        user_id: this.userId,
        widget_list_id: this.editForm.widget_list_id,
        widget_type: this.editForm.widget_type
    })
}
```

Comment: This can be done in one line of code. `this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0] = Object.assign({}, this.editForm)`

Comment: @connexo that wont work, it would have the same result as what OP tried, he could do `Object.assign(this.sets.filter(s => s.id === res.body.last_id)[0], this.editForm) `, but then `user_id` needs to be manually added as it comes from `this.userId` instead of `this.editForm.user_id`